# Can I access the id of the parent object inside a named_scope when fetching associated objects with the 'others' method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, named-scope

Let's say you have two models: `articles` and `comments`.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

You know you can fetch associated comments to an article like this:

```
article = Article.first
article.comments # => SELECT * FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments".article_id = 123)
```

Is there a way to explicitly access the `article_id` (123) within a named_scope?

I need this for a complex named_scope that joins another table. Basically the named_scope will depend on to be called from the associated parent object to make sense (`article.comments.my_named_scope` and **not** `Comments.my_named_scope`).

I don't want to pass the id as a parameter for the named_scope. So, instead of passing the `article_id` to the named scope with `... lambda { |article| ...}` and access the id with `"... #{article.id} ..."`, I want to somehow access this `article_id` that the [`others` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) uses, which I get from the `has_many` association.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like what you're actually after is an association extension:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions

In particular, `proxy_owner`, which will be the @article in question

eg:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts do
    def sample_extension
      puts "Proxy Owner #{proxy_owner}"
    end
  end
end

@article.posts.sample_extension
```

Comment: Originally, I wanted to access the parent's object id for use in a JOIN statement of my named_scope. This doesn't seem to be possible.  
But it **is** possible when I use an association extension and use the `proxy_owner` variable.

So, this is not exactly how I would like to have it worked, but still good. Thanks for your answer, Mark.

Comment: proxy_owner() is [deprecated](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy/proxy_owner) from Rails 3.1.0. In the newer version of Rails, the owner object can be simple accessed using `@association.owner` method inside the extension or using another alternative method. Code snippets are in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Been struggling with the same issue. You can try this, which is a more elegant than using association extensions:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.get_article_id
    self.new.article_id
  end
end

@article = Article.new
@article.posts.get_article_id
```

Within class methods for Post, you can now just use `get_article_id` anywhere you need the ID of the parent article. With proxy associations, I wasn't able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I like @ajkochanowicz's solution but looks like there's a DB hit involved there (Rails 3.2.x), so just a heads up, not really ideal considering the fact that you already have the parent object on hand somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

#### For Rails 4 and above

The newer way to do it in Rails4+ is:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments do
    def my_named_scope
      puts "Scope Owner = #{@association.owner}"
    end
  end
end

article = @article.comments.my_named_scope
```

Inside the scope `my_named_scope`, `@association.owner` returns the `Article` object that `.comments` was called on. Hence the `article` returned by the code above is same as the `@article` object.

#### Alternative method

If you don't want to use extensions and would rather avoid the "create a new object and get id from there" method (as described by Chanpory's answer), here is how to do it:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.get_article_id
    Comment.scope_attributes["article_id"] # scope_attributes returns a hash of all the attributes inherited from the owner of this scope
  end
end

@article = Article.find(10)
@article.comments.get_article_id  # returns 10
```